# how position an anchor element in data cell of the table before the table at the beginning of the line?

Tags: html, css, css-position

There is need to position an anchor element in the data cell of the table 20px right from the very beginning of the data cell line. How it can be done?
Position:absolute did not help.

The HTML code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p
{
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 30px;
}

.a_text_i
{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
    top: 4px;
    /*left: -60px;*/
    height: 12px;
    width: 15px;
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    line-height: 11px;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #3F8FFF;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.a_text_i:hover
{
    color: #333;
/*    transition: all 0.0s;*/
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F0F0F0 0pt,     #3F8FFF 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#F0F0F0,#3F8FFF);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F0F0F0,#3F8FFF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#F0F0F0,#3F8FFF);
}

.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=p2>
<P>We have to position the first anchor element with id=4991 containing letter "i" 20px right from the left edge of the div with id=p2</P>

<TABLE id=p1012 style="WIDTH: 90%; MARGIN-LEFT: 70px" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 border=1>
<TBODY vAlign=top>
<TR>
<TH width=50>Col 1</TH>
<TH>Col 2</TH>
<TH>Col 3</TH>
<TH>Col 4</TH>
<TR>
<TD>1.</TD>
<TD>11</TD>
<TD><A id=p4991 title="title of the link" class="a_text_i"  href="http://www.google.com" target=_blank>i</A> 
<P id=p4992>Providing Services</P></TD>
<TD>-</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY></TABLE>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add position: relative to td, then you can use absolute for the anchor . set left : 20px: to anchor https://fiddle.jshell.net/k00xhua7/

Comment: I've added position:relative to td and set position:absolute for the anchor's a_text_i style, but still the anchor is positioned in the td, not from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Please, take into account that we have to position the anchor at the very beginning of the line of td before the table and not in the td.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I set position:relative not for the "td" but for "tr" and left to -50px and the anchor was positioned in desired position.

Comment: i've another question. We have 3 paragraphs in the TD. <TD><P id=p4992>Providing Services 1</P><P id=p4993>Providing Services 2</P><A id=p4991 title="title of the link" class="a_text_i"  href="http://www.google.com" target=_blank>i</A> 
<P id=p4994>Providing Services 3</P></TD>  and have to position the anchor before the 3rd <p>. How it can be done? Is it possible to get the top value for <p id=p1994>?

Comment: For another question than the original question you need to post a new question.